# Preserving the original image color of the selected and unselected UITabBar icons

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

The structure is the following:

In my storyboard, I have a `Tab Bar Controller` which contains a `Tab Bar` object. This object has a custom class in which I have only this method:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  NSArray *imageNames = @[@"test1", @"test2", @"test3", @"test4", @"test5"];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      UITabBarItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *imageName = [imageNames objectAtIndex:i];
      item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
      item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-selected"]];
    }
}
```

I have created an `Asset Catalog` which contains my tab bar icons, both the selected and unselected versions (different colors).

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_56) for `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` mentions *Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template.* which should preserve the original image color. This doesn't seem to happen and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372269/uibarbuttonitem-with-uiimage-always-tinted-ios-7) suggestion didn't work either.

**What happens instead is that in the selected state, my tab bar icons get the default blue tint color.**

One thing that I noticed is that if I do the following (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-ios-7)) in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the `AppDelegate`, then I can set the color of the selected tab bar icons as I want:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

The documentation for the `setTintColor` mentions:

> The tint color to apply to the tab bar’s tab bar items.
>   Starting in iOS 7.0, the tint color that applies to a tab bar’s tab bar items is the first nondefault tint color in the view hierarchy, starting with the tab bar itself.

Does this mean that regardless of my tab bar icons's color (original in the images themselves), in the selected state they will always have the color of `tintColor` ?

Or am I doing something wrong/missing something?

I'm having this issue on iOS 7.0 and 7.1.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Perfect question, really well explained.

You are not setting `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` for the selected image.

**Just should add** `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`to the `selectedImage`:

```
  item.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766669/1381708).

Comment: That was it! I really didn't see that. I was so convinced that it's because the 'tintColor' overrides the color of the image. Yep, beginner mistakes. Thank you, Gabriel! Solved!

Comment: Nice but it works on second time not on the first time

Answer (score 37):

Just go to your image assets properties, and set Render as property to "original image"

[image]

And you're good to go!

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't turn grey when it is not selected, so I don't think this is the right answer for the question asked. Good to know though.

Comment: yeah that's the question, if you needed it to change colors make it as a template

Comment: unbelievable... 

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**:

```
    for item in self.tabBar.items!{
        item.selectedImage = item.selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        item.image = item.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting *non-selected* image to **always original render** and *selected* one to **always template render** did the trick for me.

Solution for **iOS 13** and **swift 5.1**

```
let item = UITabBarItem(title: "item_title",
                        image: UIImage(named: "img")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
                        selectedImage: UIImage(named:"img_selected")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
```