# Custom Tabbar and Tabbar Button item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an idea for an app, but after a few months of dealing with Xcode I've run into a major design issue. I want this:

[image: Wanted Navigation & Tabbar Design]

But as many ios developers know, using the traditional tabbar in the interface builder will only create single color, non-outline, tab bar buttons like so:

[image: Unwanted Design of Tabbar]

Is there any code/sdk where I can perhaps achieve the design of the first image while still having the tab bar functionality of the second?

Edit: The approach I'm looking for is more towards creating a custom tabbar controller all together, which has been answered.

Comment: You can use collection view to create your own custom tab bar. And use container view to change the view controllers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving the original image color of the selected and unselected UITabBar icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846652/preserving-the-original-image-color-of-the-selected-and-unselected-uitabbar-icon)

Comment: @AshishKakkad would the Collection view be the tabbar itself? sorry i don't have much experience with uicollection views.

Comment: yes @JevonÇøö collection view is the one way to acheive the design ,else  you can use container view with 5 buttons in it and position it in the top , hide the tabbarcontroller in storybaord based button selection change the index of tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to create a seperate view for custom Tabbar.
I will suggest you:

1. In your main.storyBoard , take two containers one for tabBarController  and another for CustomTabBarViewController
2. Draw your custom tabbar UI in  CustomTabBarViewController
3. Attach all other controller in tabbar.